# Что такое вызывающий поток STA?

Tags: .net

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой. Никак не пойму в чем дело. Суть вот в чем: при попытке подключиться к серверу ATAS (программа трансляции онлайн котировок фьючерсов с биржи), выдает ошибку - "сервер недоступен", и после многочисленных попыток когда все-таки удается подключится, связь с сервером разрывается, и программа выдает сообщение - "Соединение разорвано. Вызывающим потоком должен быть STA, поскольку этого требуют большинство компонентов". Что это значит, подскажите, пожалуйста? Грешил вначале на провайдера, сменил, то же самое. В тех. поддержке платформы говорят что проблема с соединением, но связь со всеми остальными серверами, сайтами отличная. Думаю что собака зарыта именно в этом STA? но я не знаю что это такое. Помогите

Comment: в [mсдн](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.stathreadattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). проверьте стоит ли у вас этот атрибут?

Comment: Это значит, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к вашему UI не из UI-потока. Или у вас какая-то компонента используется из фонового потока. Покажите код.

Comment: Вангую, что вы WinForms WebBrowser пытаетесь запустить в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Grundy, VladD, Alexander Petrov - ребята уважаемые, прошу разъясните ваши ответы подробнее. Гуглил ваши ответы, чтобы понять о чем вы, не могу понять. Я не программист, а просто человек столкнувшийся с проблемой. И еще добавлю, что эта проблема не на одном компе, я с нескольких пробовал, то же самое.

Comment: @Divergent: Ну, хм. Слишком много возможных причин. Для начала, пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь отладчиком (вы знаете, что это такое, надеюсь), и приведите в вопросе (его можно редактировать) точный текст исключения и (особенно важно) stack trace. Без этого невозможно вам помочь.

Comment: VladD, а как им воспользоваться? (ваши надежды неоправданы, извините) В контексте данной проблемы я не знаю что такое отладчик, откуда его взять, с какой стороны подойти..

Comment: @Divergent, у вас есть исходный код программы?

Comment: @Divergent: Ну, вы пользуетесь Visual Studio. Если вы запускаете программу из-под него, она работает в отладчике. В любом случае, у вас должен быть кто-то рядом, кто понимает, что такое отладчик и поможет вам научиться им пользоваться. В противном случае нам будет очень сложно вам реально помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Как написали вам в комментариях, это значит что вы обращаетесь к вашему UI(интерфейсу) не из потока в котором был вызван этот UI (Интерфейс). Заранее прошу прощение за более разжеванное цитирование, просто старался сказать более понятным языком.

Решить данную проблему можно следующим образом.
 1. Как посоветовали опять же вам в комментариях воспользоваться отлатчиком и посмотреть конкретнее где проблема.
 2. Воспользоваться данной строкой при инициализации ( загрузки ) формы. Быть может решит проблему, но лучше подобное обходить. `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` p\s: сработает только на windows form(c#).

Надеюсь поможет.